# ssh connection timed out after transferring 4 files via scp

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, scp

I have a script that sends 8 files to the same server. Running all 8 commands separately works, but when I run the script, the 5th scp command will timeout after the 4 previous files are transferred.

I replaced the 5th command with a simple ssh command with -vvv turned on and get the following messages:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.14 [192.168.1.14] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.14 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.14 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've also tried tuning the following values in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server I'm sending files to. `ClientAliveCountMax`, `MaxSessions`, `MaxAuthTries`, but none of them solved the problem. (note: have restarted sshd after editing file)

Any thoughts on what else might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A likely explanation is that the server has a firewall which is throttling SSH connections (not uncommon to avoid bots incessantly trying to find a password). If it's UFW, use:

```
ufw status
```

to list the current values. You should see (among other things):

```
To Action  From
22 LIMIT   Anywhere
```

You can lift the restriction for specific addresses using

```
ufw insert 1 allow in from nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn
```

If it's raw `iptables`, then it's the same idea but the adequate commands are beyond my expertise (be careful to not fence you off your server).